# Moving a window to another workspace by a key combination

Tags: keyboard, windows, spaces

Is there any way to move a window to another workspace by a key combination? For example, in Ubuntu I can do that by "Ctrl+Shift+->" if I recall correctly. In mac - only by mouse? It's not convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Better Touch Tool](http://bettertouchtool.net/) to move window to different space (even move to secondary monitor). However this does not work on fullscreen windows. Here's sample setting:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18757?viewlocale=en_US :

> **Move an app window from one space to another**
>
> Place the pointer over the window’s title bar. Hold down the trackpad
>   or mouse button, then press the Control key and the Right or Left
>   arrow key.