# Alternative to F3 for moving a window to a different workspace

Tags: keyboard, mission-control, spaces

Instead of pressing F3 and then dragging a window to a different workspace,
how else can I move a window to diffeerent workspace?

Comment: Is this a „I wonder which other ways there are“ type of question or are you trying to solve a specific problem (if yes, please describe)?

Comment: @nohillside how does that matter? My question: how to move a window to a different workspace without having to use "F3 + dragging it by mouse"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving a window to another workspace by a key combination](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174202/moving-a-window-to-another-workspace-by-a-key-combination) also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to understand why additional details usually help to get better answers.